# how to create core service client using NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account

Tags: core-service

Is there anyway I may able to invoke SessioAwareCoreServiceClient using NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account from my console application?

Comment: Why do you want to invoke service with this particular account?

Comment: Console app is actually does workflow automation. Tester who will run the app from his computer/identity will not be valid user with impersonation rights in production env. hence will not able to impersonate for different activity(author/reviewer). If I am able to run the client with NT Authority then the app will able to impersonate other workflow stakeholders.

Answer (score 3):

From a console app I see two options:

1. run it as a service, configure the service to run as local system, use the current identity to authenticate
2. Run it as a user that is a valid impersonation user, and impersonate local system.